# Story telling of the future of humanity: cyborg elite class, moss or mold on counters

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, transhuman

This is a short story from around 2000, by a British author I think (possibly published in Interzone?), telling (with no characters) what the future of the human race will be.  In the near future, people develop biotechnology and become accustomed to kitchen countertops having organic (mold or moss-like) growths on them (the omniscient narrator says something like "a bare counter would be like a yard with no grass to an American suburbanite of the 1950s).  Later elite people develop into cyborg-like beings in metal shells, needing virtually nothing from the environment or each other and communicating electronically (but becoming rather unintelligent because they have no challenges), but other non-elite humans continue to exist.

The elite cyborgs were referred to using some word like "monarch" or "czar" (or something indicating their power and sovereignty)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is Geoffrey Landis's [*A History of the Human and Post-Human Species*](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?98959)

Quotes from the story that match my memory - first, regarding mold

> In a house, every clear surface became covered with a fine, downy
> coating of mold, and after a while, humans adopted a mindset that this
> is right and natural - a surface bare of mold would be like a lawn bare of vegetation

and second, about post-humans called "potentates"

> First among these splinters was the set of humans who had control over
> technology . They had , by any older reckoning , nearly infinite power

and

> Over the course of a hundred millennia , the potentates evolved.
> Intelligence was no longer a selection force.

I wasn't right that the writer was non-American - Landis is American, but it was published in a magazine that's less familiar to me (Science Fiction Age).

I need to credit this [question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/272485/im-looking-for-a-short-story-involving-time-tower-minds)'s answer for leading me to the answer.  That answer mentioned an anthology called [Supermen: Tales of the Posthuman Future](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pl.cgi?33840) which sounded familiar, so I checked the Table of Contents and found the Landis story.