# I'm looking for a short story involving Time Tower minds

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

I'm looking for a short story, perhaps in a volume of *Year's Best SF* or *The Year's Best Science Fiction* that involves "Time Tower minds" which have a stretched consciousness across time, allowing an approximation of prescience, though with negative impact on sanity.

Comment: I think I've read this. The protagonist was quite surprised to learn that one of the consequences of these supercomputers was insanity or depression for those who worked around them. In the end he taught them Zen(?) and everyone who worked near them became unnaturally calm

Comment: It seems a long shot, but there is a very strange story called [Grist](https://www.goodreads.com/en/book/show/9480538) by Tony Daniel that has humans referred to as _Time Towers_. They can see the future to some extent and they're all two books short of a trilogy. But it's a **very** strange story. It was in [The Year's Best Science Fiction 16th Annual Collection](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pl.cgi?50827), though I first read it in the anthology _Supermen Tales of the Posthuman Future_. Let me know if you think this is it and I'll post it as an answer.

Comment: That is the one! You are a star!

Comment: I remember now it is also in his collection of short stories "The robot's twilight companion" and includes the very good "A dry, quiet war". Thanks again.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is [Grist](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?83357) by Tony Daniel. It was published in in [The Year's Best Science Fiction 16th Annual Collection](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pl.cgi?50827) as you remembered, though I first read it in the anthology [Supermen Tales of the Posthuman Future](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pl.cgi?33840).

[Goodreads](https://www.goodreads.com/en/book/show/9480538) summarises the story as:

> The Grist is the goo of life that links humanity with the collective consciousness of every living thing. Andre Sud, itinerant priest and expert rock balancer, searches for the Large Array Personality (LAP) known as Thaddeus Kaye, who threatens the delicate balance of interstellar events with his suspected ability to control the future.

But it's a lot stranger than that. It's laid out as a number of apparently unconnected sub-stories one of which involves a family of rats as I recall. The *Time Towers* were an experiment in *post humanism* that largely failed, though one of them, Thaddeus Kaye, has acquired powers that have become dangerous.

Comment: I've just reread the story, and it is entirely as strange as I remember.  It will be interesting to see what the two following novels are like...